# Как сверстать такую схему?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

Как сверстать такую схемку? Или проще вставлять рисунком?

[image: Схема]

Comment: Хоть вопрос и закрыт, как дубликат, у вас есть возможность отметить хороший ответ `Vitaliy Antal`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.tree {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.tree ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #628bb1;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 2px solid #628bb1;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 2px solid #628bb1;
  border-radius: 0 2px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 2px solid #628bb1;
}
.tree li a {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #5197d8, #a8ccff);
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">JIRA</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Group</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">User1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">User2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Project Role</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">User3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">User4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```